# windows application layout color is changed on the system theme changing

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am working on  Universal Windows platform(UWP) for windows-10.
I have issue regarding a application layout color change.My issue is, Whenever i am changed my device(Laptop/Tabulate/Mobile) theme that time my application theme color is also affected as per the  theme changed.

Example : I changed my laptop theme to High contrast that time my windows app theme is also  affected so whole layout of the app is changed.

so kindly suggest me what should i do?

Comment: Please provide additional information. What exactly is changed? When using theme colors, they change according to theme changes. That is the intended behavior.

Comment: @KaiBrummund: Actually my application theme is affected only when the user select a High contrast them for his/her computer system.Means if my application have a black font color then that font will not be displayed because in the High contrast them the background is black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually my application theme is affected only when the user select a High contrast them for his/her computer system.Means if my application have a black font color then that font will not be displayed because in the High contrast them the background is black.

A UWP app supports high-contrast themes by default. This default support is based on using the default themes and templates. These themes and templates make reference to system colors as resource definitions, and the resource sources change automatically when the system is using a high-contrast mode.

You can find the resources in the generic.xaml file and themeresources.xaml of the project. So one **Bad** solution is that you can override all the `HighConrtrast` resources to normal one in your project. You can find these two files in the possible path like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic`, and one of the `HighContrast` resources is like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
    <!-- High Contrast theme resources -->

    <!--
    ****************************************************
    HIGH CONTRAST COMMON CONTROL COLORS
    ****************************************************
    -->

    <Color x:Key="SystemAltHighColor">#FF000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltLowColor">#33000000</Color>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

> so kindly suggest me what should i do?

My suggestion is that leave the `HighContrast` be there, when we develop an app, we should concern the people of light color blindness. And for `HighContrast` mode, **DON'T** use a color just because you like it. That’s why I said this is not recommended.

But it doesn't mean you can't modify the layout in the `HighContrast` mode, you can refer to the official document [High-contrast themes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/high-contrast-themes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: :I did not understand your solution . Actually I just want that my app theme color will remain as it is when user select a high contrast theme.Its means no theme should be affected to my  application.

Comment: @HardikKothari, and I was trying to tell you we can't disable the high contrast mode, we can only modify the color value in this mode and we should carefully modify them, and replacing the entire high contrast resources with normal resources is absolutely not a good solution.

Comment: @HardikKothari, I should say there seems to have a method to disable the high contrast mode for the css of winjs UWP project, I haven't tested, but since you mentioned that you used xaml, so I didn't mention this.

Comment: Ok i understand so please suggest me which solution is best for me and how to modify color value in high contrast ?

Comment: @HardikKothari, I gave you a link in the end of my answer, in that document there is sample. I suggest just modifying some of the color by declaring some resources in your `Application.Resources`, just refer to that link, there is sample code.

Comment: How to disable a high contrast mode for the app?

Comment: @HardikKothari, no way to do that.